# django ckeditor won't show on the form

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, ckeditor5

Followed every step mentioned in https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, but when I view the form, I don't get any editor. Also I did run "python manage.py collectstatic"

settings.py specific to ckeditor.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = STATIC_ROOT+"/ckeditor/ckeditor"

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "ck_uploads/"
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL+'media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'media')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

forms.py

```
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget

class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title','brief','content','accept_comments','is_public')

        brief = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
        content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
```

---

No suggestions worked so far (including moving the widget definition out of Meta).

I am custom rendering the forms and this is how the field is getting rendered in the form.

```
{{ form.details }}
```

Also rendering the whole form using `{{ form.as_p }}` didn't make any difference.

This is what the HTML field shows when I use Chrome developer tools --> Elements.

```
<textarea cols="40" id="id_details" name="details" rows="10" required="" data-processed="0" data-config="{&quot;skin&quot;: &quot;moono-lisa&quot;, &quot;toolbar_Basic&quot;: [[&quot;Source&quot;, &quot;-&quot;, &quot;Bold&quot;, &quot;Italic&quot;]], &quot;toolbar_Full&quot;: [[&quot;Styles&quot;, &quot;Format&quot;, &quot;Bold&quot;, &quot;Italic&quot;, &quot;Underline&quot;, &quot;Strike&quot;, &quot;SpellChecker&quot;, &quot;Undo&quot;, &quot;Redo&quot;], [&quot;Link&quot;, &quot;Unlink&quot;, &quot;Anchor&quot;], [&quot;Image&quot;, &quot;Flash&quot;, &quot;Table&quot;, &quot;HorizontalRule&quot;], [&quot;TextColor&quot;, &quot;BGColor&quot;], [&quot;Smiley&quot;, &quot;SpecialChar&quot;], [&quot;Source&quot;]], &quot;toolbar&quot;: &quot;Custom&quot;, &quot;height&quot;: 291, &quot;width&quot;: 835, &quot;filebrowserWindowWidth&quot;: 940, &quot;filebrowserWindowHeight&quot;: 725, &quot;toolbar_Custom&quot;: [[&quot;Bold&quot;, &quot;Italic&quot;, &quot;Underline&quot;], [&quot;NumberedList&quot;, &quot;BulletedList&quot;, &quot;-&quot;, &quot;Outdent&quot;, &quot;Indent&quot;, &quot;-&quot;, &quot;JustifyLeft&quot;, &quot;JustifyCenter&quot;, &quot;JustifyRight&quot;, &quot;JustifyBlock&quot;], [&quot;Link&quot;, &quot;Unlink&quot;], [&quot;RemoveFormat&quot;, &quot;Source&quot;]], &quot;language&quot;: &quot;en-us&quot;}" data-external-plugin-resources="[]" data-id="id_details" data-type="ckeditortype"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 5):

### Ck editor

Step 1: `pip install django-ckeditor`

Step 2: `INSTALLED_APPS = ['ckeditor',]`

Step 3: GO TO==> `models.py` and add text field `RichTextField`

Like this:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Step 4: `python manage.py makemigrations and migrate`

Step 5: Now check the admin page, `ckeditor` is apply in textfield

#### If you want to add ckeditor in html file

Step 6: in `forms.py`

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','text',)
```

Step 7: in html file add two line of code:

```
{{ form.text | safe }}
{{ form.media }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this tutorial [by Samuli Natri](https://youtu.be/L6y6cn1XUfw).
In my case I created a model:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Article(models.Model):
    title = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self): #redirects to detail view of this post
        return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

and then in the my views.py I have class based view that does not require creating a form.

```
from django.views.generic import(CreateView)
from .models import Article

class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ['title', 'content']
```

it is important the your html has the following tags

```
<form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.media }} <!-- ckeditor thing -->
      {{ form }}
      <button class="btn" type="submit">Post</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You placed wrong the following two lines.

```
brief = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
```

They must be out of Meta class, so it will be the following.

```
class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    brief = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())

    class Meta():
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title','brief','content','accept_comments','is_public')
```

Comment: didn't make much difference.